Can a switch be put on the collector side of npn BC547 rather than the base side?
here is the attached image showing 2 different configurations of npn BC547 transistor.

In the first diagram, the relay is ACTIVATED by supplying 12V at the base of the transistor.
Now, using similar circuit diagram, I have the following questions:

Can I put the switch at the load side of the transistor rather than the base side? Will the circuit works the same as the first one? What difference will be there between these two configurations?

If both configurations are working the same, then, what if the switch at the second diagram is ON and OFF after every say 30 seconds to activate the relay??



What would be the point of the transistor in the right circuit?

both configurations will work the same if they are the same

the switch in the right diagram has to carry more current

if they are the same, then, what is the outcome with regards to my point 2? Is it same as first diagram?

@SinChan What do you mean "what if the switch is ON and OFF after 30 seconds...?". You tell us what that means. Personally, circuit 2 makes no sense unless you are hiding salient information.

@ZOGAM - Hi, You changed the question significantly after receiving answers to the original version. That behaviour is not allowed here, since that change makes all the previous answers look wrong/incomplete, as they don't address the new parts you added to the question (this is sometimes called a "chameleon question"). After answers have been received then only clarifying a question is allowed, and even then, only if the change doesn't invalidate existing answers (your change does :( ). Therefore I reversed (rolled-back) your changes to the question.

(cont'd) It seems you asked a very specific question here, but removed too much of the context. That means you got answers to the specific question, but they were not going to be enough for you, as those answers may not have applied in the (originally undisclosed) context of your overall design. || I recommend you consider which of the answers to your original question best answered that one. Then, if you need to ask a follow-on question, ask that separately, include all relevant context & a link to this one for context & explain how your follow-on is different.

Both in theory are the same. Rev A.
(1) has Ic leakage current when off but negligible 15nA in BC547.
(2) Transistor is redundant. Not needed unless controlled by logic.
Both have reverse-biased diode with added series resistor equal to coil resistance approx. to speed up opening due to L/R=Tau.( If speed is important .e.g. inductive contact load )
Power disspation is negl. since BJT saturates 12V coil easily.
Rbase  = 10 to 20x R.coil to control Ic/Ib ratio.


15nA* max? Arcing should be pretty low with the diode in there, I suppose depending on how the supply is wired.

I will add a diode IN4007 just after the switch in the second diagram. Will this helps?

TY TIm..............

The two circuits are not the same.  They achieve the same function in different ways.
A significant difference between the two circuits is that in the right circuit, both the transistor and the switch are carrying 100% of the relay coil current, while in the left circuit the transistor is carrying 100% of the coil current, but the switch is carrying only 10% (or less) of the that current level, none of which goes through the coil.

In the first circuit the relay is turned on by the transistor when base current flows.
In the second circuit the relay is turned on by the transistor only when the switch is also turned on. The switch location makes the transistor redundant.
Here's the simplified circuit.


Your two designs will have identical behaviour.
The only reason you'd use a transistor at all is if you want to control the relay using a low power signal, such as the output from a microcontroller. The way you have drawn your schematics implies that there's no microcontroller, no low-power signal for control, and a transistor is not needed. This would do:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Your left design has the advantage that the switch can have a much lower current rating (and is consequently cheaper), since it is passing only a fraction of the current passed by the switch in the right-hand circuit. It should also last longer, when opened and closed many times, for the same reason.
Also, it's never a good idea to leave a transistor's base unconnected, so a large-value resistance should hold it at ground potential when the switch is open:

simulate this circuit
When switch SW1 is open, the relay coil is permanently unpowered. When SW1 is closed, coil current can be switched on and off by the microcontroller. Of course the microcontroller is still optional, and you could replace it with a positive voltage source, but that would render the transistor pointless.



Can I put the switch at the load side of the transistor rather than the base side? Will the circuit works the same as the first one? What difference will be there between these two configurations?


Functionally the same but this will eliminate the need of the transistor i.e. the transistor becomes totally unnecessary. What's the point of using the transistor then?
The idea of using the transistor as a switch is to control a load with a smaller current and, when necessary, with a different voltage. For example, you can't drive a 12V relay from a 3V3 MCU. Transistor allows you to drive the relay from an MCU pin. Or, if you have a sensor that outputs 12V but the driving capabilities are not enough to drive a relay then you can use a transistor to amplify the capabilities.
Two problems with the 2nd circuit:

Constant dissipation: Because the 12V is always there and drives the B-E diode of the transistor, there's going to be a constant dissipation. This is not a desired thing for battery-operated systems.
Switch current rating: The switch carries relay coil current whilst it carries the base drive current in the 1st circuit.

The only meaningful point of using a load-side switch I can think of is safety i.e. if you want a safety stop/breaker then a switch at load-side could be meaningful. Oher than that, simply ditch the transistor and carry on.


If both configurations are working the same, then, what if the switch at the second diagram is ON and OFF after every say 30 seconds to activate the relay??


The above still applies, though I don't think I fully understood the question.
